# Segmentation fault when searching in vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when I am trying to search for a specific value in a vector. The vector is of type Person

```
struct Person{
    string name;
    string address;
    string email;
    string number;
    string SocialSec;
    string other;
};
```

Here is my search function:

```
void searchContact(vector<Person> &people) {
    string searchTerm;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter search term: ";
    getline(cin, searchTerm);
    vector<Person>::iterator it=find(people.begin(), people.end(), searchTerm);

    if (it != people.end()){
        cout << *it;
    }else{
        cout << "Element not found\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the operator overloading for == and << operators:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, const Person &it){
    stream << it;
    return stream;
}

    bool operator==(const Person &lhs, const string &rhs){
        return lhs.name == rhs;     
    }
```

This is how the segmentation fault looks like:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555565ae in operator<< (
    stream=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff8>, 
    it=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7feff0>) at class.cpp:114
114 ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, const Person &it){
(gdb)
```

Doing a backtrace:

```
#1  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#2  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#3  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#4  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#5  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#6  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#7  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#8  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#9  0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#10 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#11 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#12 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#13 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#14 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#15 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#16 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#17 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
#18 0x00005555555565c9 in operator<< (stream=..., it=...) at class.cpp:115
```

Why is this occurring, and how can I fix this?
Is it a stack overflow?

EDIT: added the operator<< overload in the original post for clarification.

Comment: This is definitely a stack overflow, and it has nothing to do with your search: it's your `operator<<` that's buggy. Please post its code if you want us to be able to help.

Comment: Looks like you overloaded << operator to accept a `Person`? Can you provide it?

Comment: You say *Here is the operator overloading for == and << operators:* but the posted code does not have the `operator<<`.

Comment: Looks like you have infinite recursion in your `<<` operator.

Comment: @user4581301 I fixed it now, sorry i am a bit tired...

Comment: No worries. Going to delete the nag comment. Feel free to clean up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator should print the primitive types of your Person class. Like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, const Person &it){
    stream << "This is the name: " << it.name;
    return stream;
}
```

If you do stream << it inside of your function, it will keep trying to print Person in an infinite recursion call.